# Maven Build JAR for Test Case

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit

i have spring boot selenium web driver project on eclipse using maven. i run the test in `scr/test/java` and put all element, pages, configuration in `scr/main/java`.

now i want to create executable jar. how to do this? is it possible? i want it to run from cmd like `java -jar mytask.jar`

so far i tried using mvn clean install, mvn clean package to generate .jar file. but when i tried to run it, it doesn't work. it runs the main in `scr/main/java`. i want to run in `scr/test/java`

this is my test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import com.bca.magenta.pages.HomePage;

    @SpringBootTest
    class ApplicationTests {
    
        @Autowired
        HomePage homePage;
    
        @Autowired
        WebDriver driver;
    
        @BeforeEach
        public void before() {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    
        @Test
        public void test() throws InterruptedException {
            homePage.testInsert();
        }
    
        @AfterEach
        public void after() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    
    }
```

this is my main class in `src/main/java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);     
    }
}
```

when i run in eclipse as junit. it run as i expected. but how to run this in jar?

Comment: Why do you need to run the tests as an executable jar? Those can be run as a usual test... ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), here's an [example](https://github.com/gregclinker/blackbox-tester/blob/master/pom.xml):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: after i run with maven clean install. it creates 3 jar. i run it one by one, no one running. i mean, it runs, but from scr/main/java. not from scr/test/java

Comment: @Vodka I see your problem, let me take a look.